# How many numbers get both ringed and crossed?

Tags: algorithm, math

`Jason rings every multiple of 13 less than 500. He then crosses every multiple of 17 less than 500. How many numbers get both ringed and crossed?`

It is an entrance test question with the following answers.

- 10
- 0
- 1
- **4**

As per the answer sheet **the answer is 4** but we don't know how to get the mentioned answer.

Please refer the following table results. As per that following table results we could not cross any thing but we can round all the 13 multiples which is 38. However we couldn't even see that answer in the list.

It would be greatly helpful if you could help us get to get that answer?

May be a silly question but did we understand the question correctly?

[image]

Comment: You won't be able to find any results with a spreadsheet that way, since mathematically speaking, `17 * k ≠ 13 * k` for any integer `k`. One way to solve this would be to use a spreadsheet by opt for two variables, `17 * 13 = 13 * 17`. That's one way, but potentially slow and time consuming to code.

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be 2? 221 and 442

Comment: @TrebledJ, agreed. You could argue that 0 is also a common multiple, so the answer sholud be either 2 or 3.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming

Comment: @TrebledJ, I am sorry but I couldn't map your answer to the equation as I don't understand it. Since we have the answer which is 4 I am not sure how to get it. Once we found the way, then I think we can think for the optimisation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, it is an interview question in which the expectation is find an algorithm to solve the above. But I couldn't explicitly state / provide any further information related to it as it is confidential. So I don't think it is an off-topic question as I don't even know or understand the question. I hope you undersstand and help me to arrive the given answer which is 4.

Comment: So what? If you have a problem with your implementation then give a [mcve], but otherwise it's not on topic here. And you can't find a way to get an answer of 4, because that's *not* the answer.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, it is not a bug which I can either reproduce it or not. It is straightforward question and expecting an a way or an algorthim to find the give answer which you said we can't get it. I just quickly created a spreadsheet to map the actual answers and found anymatch so I was bit confused and that is the reason even I mentioned is that I understand the question properly.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe, I think your answer is incorrect and here I found to how to get the right answer 4. https://imgur.com/a/ROJFdgr . Not sure why you down voted this question however, it would be greatly appreciated if you could remove it as I attach the way to get the answer. - Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, @TrebledJ. Now I understood what you are suggesting and found the answer.

Comment: That picture shows the answer isn't 4, and this still isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple algorithmic solution could go something like this:

```
    void PrintMultiplesOfXandYuptoZ(int x, int y, int limit)
    {
        int cx = x;
        int cy = y;

        while (cx < limit && cy < limit)
        {
            if (cx == cy)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cx);
                cx += x;
                cy += y;
            }
            else if (cx > cy)
            {
                cy += y;
            }
            else
            {
                cx += x; 
            }
        }
    }
```